# I want To create INDEX For This Query. Is anybody create Correct Index For this Query. Which take fast response

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:-

> Select id, name, salary, location
>       FROM user_employee
>       where name like'K%' and salary >= 10000
>       group by id
>       Order by salary DESC
>       limit 10

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  It has `group by location`, but columns such as `id`, `name`, and `salary` in the `select`.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions... The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: You are using GROUP BY incorrect as Gordon Linoff and jarlh are telling you in the comments, you may want to read this.. https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  okay sir i got it , i change the group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a composite index on `name` and `salary` and a second index on location. You can add them like so:

```
CREATE INDEX `name_salary` ON `user_employee` (`name`, `salary`);
CREATE INDEX `location` ON `user_employee` (`location`);
```

The reason you need a composite index is that MySQL will be able to use one index for your entire where clause and will speed up slightly more than if you hit two separate indexes.

Comment: This is ok or not  /  CREATE INDEX `abc` ON `user_employee` (`name`, `salary`,`id`,`location`);

Comment: @kuldeepupadhyay This is ok. If you create these indexes your performance should improve.

Comment: @kuldeepupadhyay your edit is not ok though. You added the location to your composite index, which makes it unusable for your query as you posted it in your question!

Comment: thanks for guide me. actully i was read somewhere how  to make index , first add  where clause cloumns , 2nd group by or order by coloumn ,3rd select coloumns in index .

Comment: It's not an issue really, but if I'm not mistaken your index won't be used when you run your select query. If you just use the two indexes in my answer it will work

Comment: ok sir , `name_salary`  or `location`   , Can i know which index call in my query

Comment: both. first it will use name_salary to find the results, and once that is done, it will try to use the location to optimize the group by although the group by won't be optimized by a lot.

Comment: ok sir thank you ,  i will try this and i will info you tomorrow. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I prefer creating separate indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX `name` ON `user_employee` (`name`);
CREATE INDEX `salary` ON `user_employee` (`salary`);
CREATE INDEX `location` ON `user_employee` (`location`);
```

Comment: You may prefer using separate indexes but in the end, if you use a where clause the composite index will perform better.

Comment: which index call in this query.